# Saving data in file onStop and reading it in onCreate

Tags: android

I'm creating and saving data in a file in the onPause of the Base Activity but I'm reading the information in the onCreate of other activities. The thing is, the onPause saving has been called and no errors seem to appear in the logcat. However if I try to read the info in the onCreate I'm receiving the old content I had there, instead of the new one I saved.

```
    public String parseToJsonString(Object object){
            String json = gson.toJson(object);
            return json;
        }

     public static boolean save(Context ctx, String filename, String content){
            boolean wasSaved = false;

            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                fos = ctx.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                fos.write(content.getBytes());
                fos.flush();
                wasSaved = true;
                Log.d(TAG, content);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                try {
                    if(fos != null)
                        fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return wasSaved;
        }

     @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
            String jsonSettings = APP().parseToJsonString(settings);
            FileUtil.save(this, getString(R.string.file_settings_preferences), jsonSettings);
        }

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.phone_size))
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

            setContentView(R.layout.att_base_activity);
            preferences = APP().getSecuredPreferences();
            workflow = APP().createWorkflow();

            settings = getAttendanceSettings();
            Log.d(TAG, settings.toString());

            toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.ab_tool_bar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }

public AttSettings getAttendanceSettings() {
        AttSettings settings = null;

        try {
            JSONObject jsonSettings = FileUtil.getJSONContentFromFile(this,
                    getString(R.string.file_settings_preferences));
            if (jsonSettings != null)
                settings = new AttSettings(jsonSettings);
            else
                settings = new AttSettings();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return settings;
    }
```

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, help would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider using SQL database instead of plain files.

Comment: I have a Database too, and I was thinking on doing but I think the data is not too much for me to create a table with 1 register. But right now is more the curiosity of what I'm doing wrong that I cannot see :/

Comment: For one entry SharedPreferences is the way to go.

Comment: Maybe onCreate() in the new activity becomes before onPause() in the old one. Add some Log.d() statements to your code to find out. You can also easity transfer a json text in an iIntent to the new activity.

Comment: Thank you guys for the ideas, I found the problem I was saving in 2 places and the second place was overwriting the good data with the old one. The logcat suggestion helped greenapps and Bojan you are right the SharedPreferences would have been a better approach.